# Repeated kernel panics: panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8019f6799f): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from remoted since load

Tags: mac, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Montery) freezes at the loading screen. I have tried reseting SMC, PRAM, reinstalling MacOs. The problem persists and I was able to derive the kernel panic report only in a safe mode. No peripherals attached.

````
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8019f6799f): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from remoted since load
service returned not alive with context : is_alive_func returned unhealthy : device not connected (code: 0x2
service: logd, total successful checkins since load (180 seconds ago): 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: WindowServer, total successful checkins since load (150 seconds ago): 15, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: remoted, no successful checkins since load (180 seconds ago)
service: opendirectoryd, total successful checkins since load (180 seconds ago): 18, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Panicked task 0xffffff8ba7f2d000: 3 threads: pid 88: watchdogd
Backtrace (CPU 2), panicked thread: 0xffffff86db01e540, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffe5a832b690 : 0xffffff8016a81c8d 
0xffffffe5a832b6e0 : 0xffffff8016be1596 
0xffffffe5a832b720 : 0xffffff8016bd0963 
0xffffffe5a832b770 : 0xffffff8016a21a70 
0xffffffe5a832b790 : 0xffffff8016a8205d 
0xffffffe5a832b8b0 : 0xffffff8016a81816 
0xffffffe5a832b910 : 0xffffff8017315223 
0xffffffe5a832ba00 : 0xffffff8019f6799f 
0xffffffe5a832ba10 : 0xffffff8019f675f2 
0xffffffe5a832ba30 : 0xffffff8019f66971 
0xffffffe5a832bb60 : 0xffffff8017283a8c 
0xffffffe5a832bcc0 : 0xffffff8016b872e6 
0xffffffe5a832bdd0 : 0xffffff8016a5c9ab 
0xffffffe5a832be60 : 0xffffff8016a731f9 
0xffffffe5a832bef0 : 0xffffff8016bb35aa 
0xffffffe5a832bfa0 : 0xffffff8016a22256 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[D6F8B92D-3418-34BA-B42B-F553E0C44C29]@0xffffff8019f65000->0xffffff8019f67fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff86db01e540): watchdogd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
21F79

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3C587984-4004-3C76-8ADF-997822977184
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000016800000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8016a00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000016810000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8016a10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016900000
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 183789442963
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000002acab45d98
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x000000030acc9770 0x0000000000000000
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff8073560000 - 0xffffffa073560000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff8073560000 - 0xffffff8074561000
  . VM    : 0xffffff8074561000 - 0xffffff8540fc7000
  . RO    : 0xffffff8540fc7000 - 0xffffff86da893000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff86da893000 - 0xffffff8ba72f9000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8ba72f9000 - 0xffffff9073d5f000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff9073d5f000 - 0xffffff95407c5000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff95407c5000 - 0xffffff9a0d22c000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff9a0d22c000 - 0xffffffa073560000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe5328d0000 - 0xffffffe5528d0000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe5528d0000 - 0xffffffe5558d0000

last started kext at 20314425767: >driverkit.serial 6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fafcb5000, size 28672)
last stopped kext at 126338230190: >IOPlatformPluginLegacy  1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fafbb1000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5450.8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>AGPM   129
>!AHIDALSService    1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
>!A!IKBLGraphics    18.0.7
>!AGFXHDA   140.3
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.5.7
>!ABridgeAudio!C    240.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.5.7
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.7
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  126.100.13
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!ABacklight    180.8
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>BridgeAudioCommunication   240.6
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   583.100.10
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1934.121.2
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
>!AActuatorDriver   5450.14
>!AMultitouchDriver 5450.14
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5450.4
>!AHS!BDriver   5450.8
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  228.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   140.1
>!AGraphicsControl  6.5.7
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IOAudio!F  340.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.8
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1040.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1040.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.5.7
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.5.7
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  597
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOGraphics!F   597
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.14
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1040.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  533.120.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  210.120.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  456.121.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  456.121.3
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.2.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0```
````

Comment: My post was deleted with more details but my MacBook Air M1 2020 16GB also keeps rebooting at least once a day now with a quick flash of pink screen. I've disconnected all devides apart from 1 Dell 49" and connectd throug it USB Display Link 3 x Dell 25". Changed keyboards, mice, disonneceted USB HUBs etc. - still no joy and it would randomly freeze on me then reboot - very annoying during work hours!

Answer (score 0):

A kernel error is an unrecoverable problem that the core OS (the kernel) couldn’t recover from.  It could be bad hardware like an issue with the CPU, RAM or disk/storage controller.  It could also be software like if there is a programming bug instructing the OS to access something at a wrong address.

While you say “no peripherals connected,” that’s not entirely true from the system standpoint. Mac computers are highly integrated now with wireless (802.11, Bluetooh, etc.) storage and a USB keyboard and trackpad, there are still peripherals that get connected without your awareness.

From the panic, it appears to looking for a “connection” to something that didn’t get made due to a failed component.

Now, keep in mind, the debug messages could be misleading because a number of things get loaded into memory, for example. If some code to drive your AirPort card, for example put it in bad memory, the data would be corrupt but it might lead you to believe your wireless is bad when it really isn’t.  Then again, it could be a bad wireless card writing bad data into good memory.  The point is, the debug info gives (a technician, programmer or engineer) a starting point for diagnosis.

That said, most (not all) kernel panics I’ve encountered we typically memory related.  I’ve solved ,any of these issues by replacing the cheap no-name memory modules with quality brands.  If your memory is now integrated (as almost all Mac computers are now), this will require a logic board replacement.  Either way, this is something  that needs to be diagnosed more comprehensively to be solved.